# How to have arduino only turn on when enough power has been collected?

Tags: arduino, capacitor, switches, solar-cell

There was recently an article in the Christian Science Monitor about the launch of a [cracker-size satellite](http://www.csmonitor.com/Science/2011/0429/Cracker-size-satellites-to-launch-with-Space-Shuttle-Endeavour). The article says that the satellite has, "power storage in capacitors, and switching circuitry to turn on the microprocessor when the stored energy is enough to create a single radio-frequency emission — a digital beep." The power is collected from a solar cell.

I'm interested in creating an earth-based device which would do just that, collect power from a solar cell and only turn on the device to transmit when it's got enough power. I recently purchased an [arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/), but have little experience with this kind of engineering. Any suggestions about how to get started? Thanks!

Comment: Oh yeah, and don't think about sending an Arduino into space - unless you like ionizing radiation.

Comment: @LeanerRocky, I love ionizing radiation. Lets send an arduino into space.

Answer (score 7):

That satellite will presumably use "energy harvesting" (EH) to store the energy provided by the solar cell in a super capacitor. Both TI and Microchip have just started suppling evaluation kits using EH with a solar cell to power an MCU and a wireless transceiver. Advanced Linear Devices makes the [EH300 energy harvesting module](http://www.aldinc.com/pdf/EH300Brochure.pdf), which can charge a pair of super capacitors from a variety of sources, including solar cells. I've been experimenting with one, and it can provide 1.8V - 3.3V from very low voltage sources, and is capable of delivering 25 mA for 68 ms, which is more than  enough for an MCU such as an MSP430 or XLP PIC and a low-power transmitter. The EH300 has two super capacitors. They cost about £34, I bought mine from Farnell.

The Arduino isn't suitable for this application, as it won't work from such low voltages, and takes too much power. XLP PICs typically use 20 nA in deep sleep mode, and  50 uA/Mhz when active.

Answer (score 3):

You will want to look at how to put the avr into sleep mode. When in sleep mode the micro controller will turn off as much as possible to increase power savings. What you can do is hook whatever you are storing the energy from the solar panel in up to one of the ADC pins on the arduino and when that reaches a certain threshold you can wake the micro controller up.

There are a few different levels of sleep though, and the more power you want to save the more stuff gets turned off. I think ADC pins are only on with the highest/least power saving level. You could also use the avrs internal comparator, with the capacitor/battery you are storing the energy in and a voltage source for whatever voltage threshold you want.

One last thing is that using an arduino for this may not be the best.  Even in the lowest sleep state the arduino will use ~15mA, which an avr chip only uses 0.05mA in this state. The arduino has a linear voltage regulator on it that will always use up about 10mA, plus a few other extra chips. It would probably be worth it to make your own avr setup for this reason.

Comment: The ADC operates while in sleep mode?  Do you mean analog comparator?

Comment: I didn't think the avrs that arduino uses had internal comparators. After going back and looking again it turns out I was wrong! I'm not sure what sleep states they are turned off in though.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the techniques used by [voltage triggered (Type I) BEAM solar engines](http://www.solarbotics.net/library/circuits/se_t1.html).

Essentially you charge a big capacitor until voltage across it crosses some threshold, and you power your circuit by discharging it. With a big enough capacitors you should be able to power up an arduino cold. But you are going to need some *big* capacitors to feed it for >1s.

These circuits can be quite small. For example [this circuit](http://www.solarbotics.net/library/circuits/se_t1_1381.html), shown below, uses 2 transistors and a Panasonic [1381x](http://library.solarbotics.net/pieces/parts_elect_ic.html#1381).

[image: Simple type I solar engine using 1381x]

Solar engines use other techniques, e.g. slope triggering. You can find out more about them [here](http://www.solarbotics.net/library/circuits/se.html).

Answer (score 1):

I'll second the suggestion to look into the concepts behind BEAM robotics and solar engines. I think the solar engine based on the MAX8212 chip (which maxim will give you free samples of) would be the most suitable SE for you as it's the most (easily) configurable.  The arduino is a brilliant platform for learning about microcontrollers, but it's a bit power hungry for solar power. once you understand Arduino, start looking into working with at Atmel AVR chips directly. ATtiny45 is a great fun little platform to work with, and can be powered from a solar engine quite well. [Check out what I've been doing with them here](http://jimblackhurst.com/wiki/index.php?title=SolarTherm)

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with arduino and it seems from the current crop of answers to be that it draws to much power and probably doesn't have a low enough sleep current draw to make it a viable option. A nanowatt xlp PIC would be the place to start, however you still need to deal with the interface between energy harvester (solar cell in this case) and microchip. The output of the solar cell is low voltage in comparison to other forms of energy harvesters and the requirements of a PIC + circuitry, linear technology do a range of self starting dcdc converters targetted at energy harvesting applications (LTC3105 for instance) which can act as your power converter. From that point you would attach the pic across the capacitor/battery and then run it in sleep mode when the solar cell is charging the battery/capacitor. Make sure that the battery/capacitor has a full charge (or at least isn't empty) when you first run the system as the PIC will have a fairly high cold-start current draw and could stop your stored voltage every reaching beyond 0.7V - you can solve this with a 1.9V low voltage comparator if need be.

Although people have stated the arduino is too power hungry for this type of thing you can solve that problem by just using more solar cells until you are able move on to PICs etc which would allow you to make a more sophisticated system.